# how do i present my unit conversion system in UML?

Tags: architecture, uml

First time here so I'm sorry if I break any rules, I can see the website being strict on how to write questions.

I am given a task where i have to create/describe a unit conversion system in uml. It is mentioned that the system should be able to:

- a. manage units
- b. to list units and unit information
- c. to manage aliases for units
- d. to manage class of units
- e. to manage unit types

Here is what i got so far:

[image: My uml diagram]

I of course don't want you guys to make my homework for me, but could you give me some advice, tips and such on how do i present the points named above in uml?

Comment: So @Dr.man it seems that you try to model your classes in a class diagram. Is it that ? If yes say it ;) What do you want to model with the import dependency, it seems that you use it in a wrong way. Your class Unit clas is it one class or serveral classes ? By the way, class is a bad name for a class ... If you have to manage a list, why is there no list in your schema ? And what's API ?

Comment: Nope. That's too far off. You better read a book about basics first. None of the requirements is targeted with your "design" that just is a random try.